# Polarization photon and Stokes parameters

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-optics, polarization

I have the following situation: About the polarization of the photon, I introduce the basis:

Horizontal polarization $|\leftrightarrow>=\binom{1}{0}$
Vertical polarization $|\updownarrow>=\binom{0}{1}$

The density matrix in this problem is:

$$\rho =\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1+\xi _{1} & \xi_{2}-i\xi _{3}\\ 
\xi_{2}+i\xi _{3} & 1-\xi _{1}
\end{pmatrix}$$

The Stokes parameters are: $\xi _{1}, \xi _{2}, \xi _{3}$

The probability that if the photon has got lineal polarization whose axis forms an angle $\theta$ with de horizontal is:

$$|w>=cos\theta |\leftrightarrow>+sin\theta|\updownarrow>$$

$$ P_{\theta}=<w|\rho|w>=\frac{1}{2}\left ( 1+\xi_{1}cos(2\theta)+\xi_{2}sin(2\theta) \right )$$

Is there any value of the [Stokes parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_parameters) for which this probability is zero?

Comment: What about $\xi_1 = \xi_2 = 0$?

Comment: $\xi_1 = \xi_2 = 0$ won't do the trick because then the probability is 1/2. But you have three Stokes parameters that have to satisfy two conditions (first, the probability has to be zero, and second, $\xi_1^2+\xi_2^2+\xi_3^2 = 1$) so there sure is a solution.

Comment: Sorry, yes, total idiocy on my part.

Comment: What about $\xi_{1}cos(2\theta)+\xi_{2}sin(2\theta=-1$?

Comment: @user15940 Yup, that will do the trick.